# Satisfaction of a formula with the universal quantifier

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Suppose we have a first order language $L$ with interpretation $M$ and domain $D$. Then a denumerable sequence $s=(s_1,s_2,...)$, where $s_j\in D$ for $j=1,2,...$, satisfies a well formed formula $B$ with $x_1,...,x_k$ as free variables if the $k$-tuple $(s_1,...s_k)$ satisfies $B$. This makes perfect sense however, I misunderstand the satisfiability of a well formed formula of the kind $(\forall x_i)B$ where $x_i$ is free in $B$. In Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic", he defines the satisfiability of such a wf by stating:

> $s$ satisfies $(∀x_i )B$ if and only if every sequence that differs
> from s in at the most $i$th component satisfies $B$

Does this mean that every sequence $s$ that differs up to the $i$th component satisfies $B$, in other words, every sequence $s$ whose components preceding the $i$th component differ,

or,

every sequence that differs in only the $i$th component satisfies $B$.

The latter seems more of an intuitive definition. A simple clarification would mean a great deal, thank you!

Comment: The basic issue is to define a "meaning" (and thus a truth value) for formulas with free variables. One of the possibilities is the "trick" of variable assignment function $s$ that maps ALL variables of the language to an object of the domain of interpretation. This defines a sort of context for the interpretation of the formula: relative to that context, a formula has meaning also when it has free variables. This amounts to saying that the *satisfaction* relation is defined not for a pair $\mathcal M,s$, where the first is the model (domain+interpretation of the non-logical symbols).

Comment: Applied to the universal quantifiers, the above "trick" amount to saying that $\forall x_i Px_i$ holds if $Px_i$ holds for **every** object of the domain. Thus, whatever is the $d$ value that the variable assignment function $s$ assign to $x_i$, the predicate $Px$ holds of it, i.e. $\mathcal M, s \vDash \forall x_i Px_i$ iff $\mathcal M, s' \vDash Px_i$, for every $s'$ that is "like"  $s$ except that assign to $x_i$ a difefrent value.